# Populating an array inside an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like the following - the code works perfectly for the first object (Id = 1) but for the second and third objects (id = 2 & id = 3) the [categoryID = 3] and not first 2 and then 3.

I have tried various permutations without any joy whatsoever.

```js
let documentItems = [{
    id: 1, //I want to copy this id as CategoryID to Items below
    title: "All Staff",
    Items: [{
        id: 3,
        // This is where I want to create the CategoryID
        PolicyName: "A Policy",
        AppliesTo: [1]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        PolicyName: "A Completely Different Policy",
        AppliesTo: [1]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Management",
    Items: [{
      id: 2,
      PolicyName: "Another different Policy",
      AppliesTo: [2, 3]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Admin",
    Items: [{
      id: 1,
      PolicyName: "A third Policy",
      AppliesTo: [2, 3]
    }]
  }
]

documentItems.forEach((el) => {
  let id = el.id
  el.Items.forEach((el2) => {
    el2.categoryID = id
  })
});

console.log(documentItems)
```

The result (of above) I have tried to illustrate the result

```js
let documentItems = [{
    id: 1, //I want to copy this id as CategoryID to Items below
    title: "All Staff",
    Items: [{
        id: 3,
        CategoryID: 1,
        PolicyName: "A Policy",
        AppliesTo: [1]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        CategoryID: 1,
        PolicyName: "A Completely Different Policy",
        AppliesTo: [1]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Management",
    Items: [{
      id: 2,
      CategoryID: 3,// SHOULD BE 2 INCORRECT
      PolicyName: "Another different Policy",
      AppliesTo: [2, 3]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Admin",
    Items: [{
      id: 1,
      CategoryID: 3, // Should be 3 - CORRECT
      PolicyName: "A third Policy",
      AppliesTo: [2, 3]
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: Is it `el.items` or `el.Items`?

Comment: What is the thing you want to populate ? What is the category ID for you ? What is the output you are expecting ?

Comment: can you provide expected output

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to change .items to .Items

Comment: sorry my bad wrong person tagged I thought the question was yours

Comment: @Wayne: We seem to not see a problem here. Can you please explain what you expected?

Comment: The result you posted doesn't match the result when your code actually runs here.

Comment: @MarkMeyer  - weird. It is a vue app so wondering if I copy this.documentItems to documentItems and try that?

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Nope, tried that and exactly the same result